# Is there a way to set the Windows Vista network detection to automatically detect my wireless as a private network?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, wireless-networking

I have a home network consisting of a wired and wireless network joined. I have my main machine running Windows Vista and it detects the network as private almost instantly. However when I use my laptop with the wireless part of the network it takes a minute or more to detect that it's a private network.

Is there any way to tell Vista that if it connects to my specific (WPA-PSK secured) wireless network then it should automatically and instantly mark it as private?

The reason I ask is that whenever I want to actually use the laptop to browse files on the network it is still identifying it and therefore assumes its public and won't show me any networked computers. Also I don't want to enable file and printer sharing for all public networks.

---

**Edit:** To clarify, it already is marked as private in the Networking settings as @Molly suggested, but it still takes a minute or so to detect it and confirm that it's private. I want to know if there's a way to tell Windows that if you connect to network "Foo" (WPA-PSK secured network) with the appropriate key to instantly mark it as private without having to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

Open the **Network and Sharing Center**, click on **Customize** and make the network **Private**.

[image]

[image]